# PHP path in Jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, jplayer

I am trying to integrate a mp3 player in WordPress using the following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        var description = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
            var path_php = "<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>";

        $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
            autoPlay:false, 
            description:description,
            jPlayer:{
                swfPath: path_php+'/plugin/jquery-jplayer' 
            }
        });
    });
```

In a weird way the player is working just in Opera and IE8. The script is correct integrated because it work if i write the absolute path of the blog for the var php_path.

Can help me with what i am missing? Thanks!

later edit: if you have an idea about a different approach of how to load a wp template path in above jquery code, i am open to it.

here is the browser output for the above code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
            var description = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
            var path_php = "http://localhost/mywebsite/wp-content/themes/mythemename";

            $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
                autoPlay:false, 
                description:description,
                jPlayer:{
                    swfPath: path_php+'/plugin/jquery-jplayer' 
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Do you get any JS-related error when having a look at your script console?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure `bloginfo('template_directory')` returns an absolute URL and Flash will only load relative URL's for security reasons.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/bloginfo

EDIT:

Ignore my last comment below, try this.

```
<?php print str_replace(get_bloginfo('url'), '', get_bloginfo('template_directory'))?>
```

Comment: hello Dave. But, if i write the absolute URL, it work. I am trying to get a php function for blog path into jquery.

Comment: Try using the code below, it strips out the url part of the directory. You need to provide a URL that is relative to the page for Flash to load it. Perhaps Opera is more leniant with this.

`<?php str_replace($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'], '', bloginfo('template_directory'))?>`

Comment: Hello Dave, i tried yr solution and isn't working. the source code result is same like in my example: the correct path, but, even so...the  swfPath it seem to not load it...

Comment: Did you try the edit I made to the post? Its more likely to work. Failing that have you checked the swf has no errors in it. Could you post the output for us all to see?

Comment: yr last edit code cannot work because one syntax call the blog path and second one theme path, in same line, twice http etc. when you talk about output, you mean what i see in source code after page browser render?

Comment: Yes what is output to the browser.

Comment: I've just updated the answer, sorry bloginfo echos out the result get_bloginfo() doesn't meaning you can alter it. Try the code now.

Comment: thanks but it not working because the path now look like /wp-content/themes/mythemename

Comment: Stab in the dark but have you tried the jplayer Wordpress plugin? Looks pretty good and no need for code.. <http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mp3-jplayer/screenshots/>

Comment: yes, i know it, but i want to use a non plugin script from where i can develop custom theme options for it. the thing is that the script is work if i find the proper way to insert a php path in the swfPath. Thanks Dave for your time.

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress

```
plugins_url()
```

brings back the plugin url including the domain.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var description = 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit';
        var path_php = "<?php print plugins_url(); ?>";

    $('body').ttwMusicPlayer(myPlaylist, {
        autoPlay:false, 
        description:description,
        jPlayer:{
            swfPath: path_php.match(/http:\/\/[^\/]+(.*)/)[1]+'jquery-jplayer' 
        }
    });
});
```

So that should replace the http:// and domain with nothing, leaving you with just the plugin path and jquery-jplayer on the end.

Comment: hello Harry. The player files aren't in plugin folder, but in theme one. thing is that on source code of page, after loading the script, the path for var is correct, but not sure why the swfPath it not load it...

Answer (score 0):

Please change the $ to jQuery instead as Wordpress runs in noconflict mode, read more about it here -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_wrappers

Comment: hello, if was a jQ conflict, i think wasn't working at all. i tried anyway also with $ replacement, and still not working on FF and Safari. I discovered beside the Opera and IE, also the code work on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I just wrote a script to convert mp3 links to an audio player: http://www.bottleofbrass.com/?p=85

The Javascript code below uses jQuery to convert mp3 links to a flash player on the fly. It utilizes this flash player: http://flash-mp3-player.net.

$('#main a').each(function(){

    if($(this).attr('href')!=undefined){

    match=$(this).attr('href').match(/\.(mp3)/);

    if(match!=null){
    href=$(this).attr('href');
    text=$(this).text();

    player=  ''+text+''+
    ''+
    ''+
    ''+
    ''+
    '';


    p=$(this).parent();
    $(this).remove();
    $(p).append(player);
    }

    }

    });

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.